# How to write a generic method to insert an element in an array?

Tags: java, android, generics, methods

I have an input array [3, 5, 12, 8] and I want an output array (the input must not be affeccted) identical to the input, but with the element 7 inserted between 5 and 12, so at index 2 of the input array.

Here is what I have so far. I commented out code that doesn't event compile, and added a couple of questions that arose while trying this or that way:

```
public static <O>ArrayList<O> addToSet(O[] in,O add,int newIndex){
//    O obj = (O) new Object(); //this doesnt work
//    ParameterizedType obj = (ParameterizedType) getClass().getGenericSuperClass(); // this is not even recognized
    ArrayList<O> out = multipleOfSameSet(obj, in.length);
    if (newIndex > in.length){
        out = new ArrayList<>(newIndex+1); // also noticed that initializing an ArrayList 
        //like this throws an IndexOutOfBoundsException when i try to run out.get(),
        // could someone explain why??  
        out.set(newIndex, add);
    }
    int j = 0;
    int i = 0;
    while(j<in.length+1){
        if (j==newIndex){
            out.set(j, add);
        } else if(i<in.length){
            out.set(j, in[i]);
            i++;
        }
        j++;
    }
    return out;
}
```

The array component type could be String, Integer or even a JPanel.

Comment: @SLaks can't do what? initialize obj inside of my method?

Comment: What's that supposed to do?

Comment: @Raffaele it is supposed to create an Array of the input object and specify the contents of a particular index.

Comment: `add.getClass().newInstance()` should work if you have an empty constructor.

Comment: `out.set(newIndex, add)` doesn't work because `new ArrayList<>(newIndex + 1)` allocates an `ArrayList` with space for `newIndex + 1` elements, but it's empty; you can't set an index just in the middle randomly.  You have to actually fill the `ArrayList` with `newIndex` elements first; you can't `set` an element for an index bigger than the current size.

Comment: @EpicPandaForce add.getClass().newInstance() ran an incompatible types error. CAP#1 cannot be converted to O

Comment: Still can't understand: not the code, not even your question. I see a method that takes an array, an object and an integer and returns a list - and it's called addToSet!

Comment: @Raffaele imagine you have an array 'int[] array = {3,5,12,8}' and you want to add 'int ad = 7' between 5 and 12, the newIndex is then 2 so you run 'int[] newArray = addToSet(array, add, 2);' and output is 'newArray = {3,5,7,12,8}'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the generic version of the code

```
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
public <T> T[] insertInCopy(T[] src, T obj, int i) throws Exception {
    T[] dst = (T[]) Array.newInstance(src.getClass().getComponentType(), src.length + 1);
    System.arraycopy(src, 0, dst, 0, i);
    dst[i] = obj;
    System.arraycopy(src, i, dst, i + 1, src.length - i);
    return dst;
}
```

but you may want to specialize the method for dealing with primitive types. I mean, generics and arrays don't mix well - so you'll have troubles with int and will need to use wrapper types:

```
@Test
public void testInsertInTheMiddle() throws Exception {
    Integer[] in = {3, 5, 12, 8};
    Integer[] out = target.insertInCopy(in, 7, 2);
    assertEquals(out, new Integer[] {3, 5, 7, 12, 8});
}
```

Comment: I understand. I never even knew about arraycopy. It is going to be very useful. About using wrapper types (Integer instead if int, right), i guess casting should take care of that problem. Thanks you very much.

Comment: I mean, maybe you'll find that dealing with wrappers is tedious. If it's library code, consider similar methods at least for int and doubles. Also, if it solves your problem, please upvote and accept this answer

Answer (score 0):

You can do this way.

```
static <T> void fromArrayToCollection(T[] a, Collection<T> c) {
    for (T o : a) {
        c.add(o);
    }
}
```